# Is there a performance rationale for mixing a binary file's endianness?

Tags: endianness, shapefile

I'm writing a parser for the most common geographic data storage type, a collection of files called a "shapefile".  This is my first project where I've had to think about endianness.

It turns out that the geometry storage is mixed endian; some parts of the file are big endian, but most of it is little endian.  The shapefile standard is described [here](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf).

Is there a discernible performance rationale, or was it simply born out of historical context?  If so, do you happen to know what that historical context is?

> The integers and double-precision integers that make up the data description fields in the
>   file header (identified below) and record contents in the main file are in **little endian** (PC or Intel®) byte order. The integers and double-precision floating point numbers that make up the rest of the file and file management are in **big endian** (Sun® or Motorola®) byte
>   order.

Comment: Git seems to do the same thing with pack files, as indicated in [this](https://codewords.recurse.com/issues/three/unpacking-git-packfiles) page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there doesn't seem to be a clear answer for it, what I've seen is a mixture of "confusion while trying to create a format that works on all platforms" and "a lot of poorly designed formats were designed back then". More info here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18969/oddities-in-the-shapefile-technical-specification

Comment: Haha. Thanks for the time delayed answer. Note the user who asked the question over there ;)

Comment: Haha, didn't notice that at all. In that case, I don't feel so bad about this thread not getting an answer until now. :P